# Force IE to open local files in the Intranet zone / trusted sites

Tags: security, internet-explorer

Is there a way to add all local files (`C:\...` or `file://`) to Trusted sites or to be recognized as from the Intranet zone? Inetrnet Explorer (11 if that matters) treats them as being in the Internet zone for which I want to keep Protected mode turned on but that causes various issues to the site I'm trying to debug locally.

There is a trick with adding

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

to the HTML file but it would be hugely inconvenient to do that for every local file. Is there a better way? Possibly some wildcard path to add to Trusted sites or something like that?

Comment: Though not a perfect way, you can also try lowering the default security settings http://mvark.blogspot.in/2008/12/how-to-avoid-ie-information-bar-during.html

Comment: Turning off protected mode works, however, I'd like to find a setup where it can be left turned on and still be able to debug Flash contents locally.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go into your IE settings (click the gear in the upper right).
2. Select 'Internet Options'
3. Select the 'Advanced' tab
4. Begin typing the word 'security' and it will automatically move your cursor along to the right section ('sec' should be enough to get you there). Alternatively, scroll down to the 'Security' section, though typing is quicker.
5. Check the box for 'Allow active content to run files on My Computer'
6. Restart your machine

Comment: I have that checkbox ticked and still need to turn off Protected mode for my Flex app to display correctly.